# Python Swap for Array for which index is generated from element itself doesn't work

Tags: python, arrays, swap

Following python swap doesn't work, the question is why !

```
nums[i], nums[nums[i]-1] = nums[nums[i]-1],  nums[i]
```

Comment: What are the inputs `nums`, `i`, and what result are you expecting?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example to illustrate why the statement does not work.

```
>>> nums=[3,2,3,4,6,5]
>>> i=4
>>> nums[i],nums[nums[i]-1] = nums[nums[i]-1], nums[i]
>>> nums
[3, 2, 3, 4, 6, 5]
```

when i is 4, the right part of the swap becomes a tuple (5,6), and it first assigns 5 to nums[4], then nums[nums[i]-1] is actually nums[5-1] which come back to nums[4] and is assigned value 6.

All the assignments occur on index 4, so no swap happens at all.